# HTML Drowdown shows selected text under image

Tags: html, css

I need the selected text to not show in the dropdown image area if my selected text is too long for the width I have set for my dropdown. I would think `text-overflow: clip;` or `overflow: hidden`, in the `span.selectInner`, would work, but it does not.

[image]

The `span.selectInner` is added with the data. Here is the snippet that adds that class:

JS

```
$('.filterSelectWrap').append('<span class="selectInner">' + filter + '</span>');
```

HTML

```
<div class="selectWrapper">
    <label class="selectLabel">Filter:</label>
    <div class="innerSelectWrapper">
        <div class="filterSelectWrap">
            <select id="filterComboBox"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.selectWrapper {
    float: left; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 5px;
}

.innerSelectWrapper {
    float: left; 
    width: 150px; 
    margin-left: 5px;
}

span.selectInner {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 5px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 22px; /* set same height */
    line-height: 22px; /* set same height */
    color: #333;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
    text-overflow: clip;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 1em;
    z-index: 901;
    background: url('../images/arrow.png') no-repeat 100% -5px #fff; /* fallback bg image*/
    background: url('../images/arrow.png') no-repeat 100% -5px, -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #9c9c9c);
    background: url('../images/arrow.png') no-repeat 100% -5px, -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #9c9c9c);
    background: url('../images/arrow.png') no-repeat 100% -5px, -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #9c9c9c);
    background: url('../images/arrow.png') no-repeat 100% -5px, -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #9c9c9c);
    background: url('../images/arrow.png') no-repeat 100% -5px, linear-gradient(top, #fff, #9c9c9c);
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

select {
    width: 100%;
    height: 22px; /* set same height */
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 902;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0 none;
    float: none;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should append the inner text `filter` inside another child div (in my case named as `.inner-text`), like:

```
$('.filterSelectWrap').append('<span class="selectInner"><span class="inner-text">' + filter + '</span></span>');
```

And give these CSS rules to `.inner-text`:

```
.inner-text {
  display: block;
  padding-right: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Have a look at the working snippet below:

```js
var filter = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates quaerat dolore iusto ducimus adipisci natus dicta, veritatis pariatur magni quos error explicabo provident iure velit dolorem odio! Sed, ratione sit.';

$('.filterSelectWrap').append('<span class="selectInner"><span class="inner-text">' + filter + '</span></span>');
```

```css
.selectWrapper {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 5px;
}

.innerSelectWrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

span.selectInner {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 5px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 22px; /* set same height */
    line-height: 22px; /* set same height */
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1em;
    z-index: 901;
    background: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-down-b-128.png') no-repeat 100%, -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #9c9c9c);
    background: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-down-b-128.png') no-repeat 100%, -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #9c9c9c);
    background: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-down-b-128.png') no-repeat 100%, -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #9c9c9c);
    background: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-down-b-128.png') no-repeat 100%, -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #9c9c9c);
    background: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-down-b-128.png') no-repeat 100%, linear-gradient(top, #fff, #9c9c9c);
    background-size: contain;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

select {
    width: 100%;
    height: 22px; /* set same height */
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 902;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0 none;
    float: none;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
}

.inner-text {
  display: block;
  padding-right: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectWrapper">
    <label class="selectLabel">Filter:</label>
    <div class="innerSelectWrapper">
        <div class="filterSelectWrap">
            <select id="filterComboBox"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this is what you are trying to achieve & it helps!

Comment: Yes, that works nicely. One problem. The CSS affects the markup when loaded but if I select a new item, I'm back to my same problem. Can I reload the CSS when a new item is selected, just in case the newly selected text is very long also?

Comment: @Wannabe You need to get the JS event when something is selected and run the same script inside it. Hope you understand.

Comment: I got it to work by re-loading the items in the drop down. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @Wannabe As soon you click the option from the select menu, you should get that event in the JS and run the same script again, this is same as reloading the `.inner-text` again & again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered something like this..

```
text-overflow: clip;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
text-overflow: "…";
```

look at this in regards to padding and usage.

```css
p {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 2px 25px 2px 5px;

    /* BOTH of the following are required for text-overflow */
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.overflow-ellipsis {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.overflow-string {
    /* Not supported in most browsers, 
       see the 'Browser compatibility' section below */
    text-overflow: " [.]"; 
}
```

```html
<p class="overflow-ellipsis">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
```

Comment: I just tried it and the select shows exactly the same as my screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

give padding right to container of text

value of padding right should be greater than or equal to width of that arrow image.

and do `text-overflow : ellipsis`

the problem is text is getting clipped at padding box and `ellipsis` does it at content box

this might help you [Prevent text from overflowing a padded container in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711490/prevent-text-from-overflowing-a-padded-container-in-html)